# Global Temporary Table VS Pipelining which one is better and why?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want to return records from function. These records should be placed in table which will be globally accessible. for inserting the records in this globally accessible table we have two option either we will use pipe lining or bulk collect into that table. What should i use and Why???

The reason for asking this question is that
In **global temporary table** we just **bulk collect into** TEM_TABLE

but in **PIPELINING**

WE LOOP THROUGH all entris from query.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have to use them in function but i don't know which one i should use and why?

Comment: That is like asking "what platform should I be on?"' without naming your destination. Then when somebody asks "where are you going" you say "I am supposed to take a train".

Comment: ok. i want to return records from function. These records should be placed in table which will be globally accessible. for inserting the records in this globally accessible table we have two option either we will use pipe lining or bulk collect into that table. What should i use. IS MY DESTINATION CLEAR NOW OR NOT???

Comment: You're last comment appears to completely change the meaning of your question.  Please *edit* your question to make it clear what you want to know.

Comment: The best approach would be straight SQL `insert into ... select ... from`.

Comment: straight insert into is not allowed by oracle. i was first trying this.

Comment: That seems unlikely.  Please post the code you reckon doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that you want the rows to be "globally accessible"? The rows in a global temporary table are not accessible from other sessions - they are only visible to the session that inserted them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global Temporary Tables are physical objects.  That means we write them to disk.  That's all overhead, so they are only useful when we have a lot of contingent data which we want to access multiple times in a session.

Pipelined functions program units for querying contingent data.  The normal use is for converting data from one shape to another shape, e.g. splitting one record into several or vice versa.  We can use a pipelined function when the data has a lifespan of a single query.

These are not oppositional constructs.  It is quite conceivable to write a pipelined function which reads records from a global temporary table, or to populate a GTT with the output of a PLF.

Answer (score 2):

**Global Temporary Table:** 
A common usage is when you have a specific user for [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) operation, loosely speaking reports.
 These reports use a lot of aggregated data and these information is reused in more than one of the reports. So it would be a good idea to **cache** the information for this session and this can be done by using temporary tables.
**Table-valued function (pipe-lined):**
Is the equivalent concept of parametric view, in oracle.
When you have got a query with sub-query(s) and in the sub-query where clause you need to specify parameter, when specifying where clause of view would not help. [samples](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/10/27/returning-a-record-set-from-a-function-in-oracle-sql-server-and-db2/) may [help](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=207).

Comment: In your OLAP scenario for reporting, aren't you describing something a materialized view would be better at?

Comment: Yes, That would be an option, but temp tables will hold data in a temporary fashion but materialized view will be a static data holder. Usages will be different also orthogonal.